# What does "move his bust around" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang

> Quite the contrary, actually. Winston Churchill, on the other hand, was terrible to his servants and family, and he was such a well-regarded leader that you can’t even move his bust around now without being yelled at.

I suspect the " move his bust around" is kind of slang or something, but i cant google it. Please explain to me what does it mean and the idea of the whole context.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Interpretation requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: If you look at a dictionary, one meaning of 'bist' is a small statue of a head.

Comment: @Mitch - I don't think I've ever heard "bist" used in that sense.

Comment: @HotLicks I know right!

Answer (score 3):

A bust is a statue of the upper part of someone's body. Often head and shoulders.

Nowadays, where a bust of Churchill sits (probably in a public space), if you (probably 'the authorities') try to move it (for example to a different plinth) this will cause controversy.

Churchill has gained a saintly reputation which the author believes is undeserved.

[image]

Comment: It's a joking reference to a recent brouhaha in the UK, when Boris Johnson scolded Barack Obama for moving a bust of Churchill out of the office because of (Johnson claimed) "the part-Kenyan president’s ancestral dislike of the British empire".